# groupby in pandas giving error when combining columns with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I want to combine the three columns `["Area (ha)", "Yield (tn per ha)", "Production (tn)"]` such that no NaNs are present:

```
    Country Crop    Season  Year    Area    Yield   Production
0   Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
22  Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
44  Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
66  Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
88  Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
110 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
132 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
154 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
176 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
198 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
220 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
242 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
264 Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715     
8754    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8776    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8798    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8820    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8842    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8864    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8886    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8908    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8930    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8952    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8974    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
8996    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
9018    Argentina   maize   1   2000        5.433   
17508   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17530   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17552   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17574   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17596   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17618   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17640   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17662   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17684   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17706   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17728   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17750   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
17772   Argentina   maize   1   2000            16780650
```

Here is what I tried:
`df.groupby(["Country", "Crop", "Season", "Year"], dropna=False).mean().reset_index()`

However I get this error: `*** TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]`

How do I fix it? Expected output is:

```
Country Crop    Season  Year    Area    Yield   Production
Argentina   maize   1   2000    3088715 5.433   5.433
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Nick, updated question to show expected output

Comment: If the missing values are actually `np.nan`, I can't replicate your problem, I get your expected output.

Comment: Check the dtypes and convert to numeric if needed. If you have empty strings in place of NaN that won't work.

Comment: thanks @mozway, I converted to numeric and still getting the same error

Comment: @user308827 can you provide **code** to set up a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Fill nan values before grouping them

```
df["Area"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df["Production"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks, I still get the same error after doing this

Comment: sorry I missed one, do that same thing for yield as well. just any columns that have nan values